# XmlDocument Searching for namespace returns children

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to convert nodes that have a namespace declaration over to use a prefix instead.    My first stab at it was to just use xslt to transform the xml, but I started looking at doing it with the XmlDocument class and using the SelectNodes() method.   The issue I am seeing is when I try to select nodes that have a namespace, it selects that node AND its children.   I assume this is because it is selecting the node which contains children.

```
<foo xmlns="some url">
    <child>child</child>
</foo>

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
var query = xdoc.SelectNodes("//*[namespace-uri()='some url']");
```

the query variable will return `<foo>` and `<child>` nodes, so when I loop through the nodes and change it to use the prefix, I get the following result.

```
<prefix:foo>
   <prefix:child></prefix:child>
</prefix:foo>
```

Is there a way to just return just the `<foo>` node in this case?   Is it better to also use xslt to transform it?

I didnt think you could change a namespace or prefix when using XDocument and XElement, so thats why I used XmlDocument.

**Update**

The result id want would be the prefix only on the node where the declaration was.   This is valid xml correct or does the prefix need to be on the children as well to be valid?

```
<prefix:foo>
    <child>child</child>
</prefix:foo>
```

Comment: This seems to be a task for XSLT as using the DOM or LINQ to XML you would have to change any element to the new prefix pretty much the same as it has to be done with XSLT, but with XSLT you can write a generic template `match="*"` and then use `<xsl:element name="prefix:{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">` to construct the needed result.

Comment: Yeah, the issue with the xslt is im having the same problem.   I dont want to change all the nodes to add the prefix, just the ones that had the namespace declaration in them.  

`<xsl:template match="//*[namespace-uri()='url'">`

Comment: Can you show us the result you want?

Comment: Without any namespace declaration it is not clear what you want to achieve? Do you want the `child` elements in the result to be in no namespace? Or to keep the namespace they had in the input document?

Comment: I added a namespace in the root node of the xml ..
`xmlns:prefix="some url"`

Then i want to go through and rename all the nodes that have the namespace declared  on the node  `<foo xmlns="some url">...</foo>`  and change it to `<prefix:foo>...</prefix:foo>`  but ONLY the foo element in this case, and not the children.    Make more sense?

Comment: To me it still isn't clear, if you have `<foo xmlns="some url">` then anything inside that default namespace declaration , like your `child` elements, has the some namespace as the `foo` element. Now you say you want to give the `foo` elements a prefix (and keep the namespace?), but it is not clear whether then `child` is supposed to be in no namespace or is supposed to keep that namespace from the input (it there inherited from the `foo` but would need to redeclare it if the namespace declarations change in the result).

Comment: Right.   I understand that the child elements would have the same namespace declaration.    I dont want the namespace declaration on the foo node, only the prefix.   I can get this part to work, but it also puts the prefix to the child nodes.   Again I know  it is under the same namespace, but if the `foo` element has it and not the `child`, does that mess up the xml or is it understood by xml that the `child` has the same namespace as `foo` even if `child` does not have a prefix or any declaration?

Comment: In a sample like `<prefix:foo xmlns:prefix="http://example.com"><child>child</child></prefix:foo>`, the `child` element is in *no* namespace while the `foo` element is in the namespace `http://example.com/`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207680/discussion-between-abbottmw-and-martin-honnen).

Answer (score 0):

In the XDM data model used by XPath and XSLT, there is no distinction between

```
<foo xmlns="some url">
    <child>child</child>
</foo>
```

and

```
<foo xmlns="some url">
    <child xmlns="some url">child</child>
</foo>
```

Logically the namespace is present on both element nodes, and its omission from the child in the lexical serialization is treated as a convenient abbreviation.

So yes, if you search for things having this namespace, you will get both elements.

Now, what are your requirements? I'm not convinced you fully understand them yourself, because the desired output you have shown is not actually well-formed (the namespace prefix is not declared). In your input, the two elements are in the same namespace; in the output, you seem to want them to be in different namespaces. If you want to process them differently, then you're going to have to use something other than the namespace to discriminate between them.

Remember that in XDM, it's the name of the node that matters, not the namespace declarations or prefixes; those are just ornamental. The name of the node is the combination of its local name and its namespace URI. You've described your requirement in terms of prefixes, but it's namespaces that actually matter.

Comment: I just was showing a small xml fragment instead of a full xml document as an example..  The xmlns was moved to the root node with a prefix in the xml and I replaced the nodes with the xmlns declarations with the prefixes after discussing it with Martin.